# How to check if Visual C++ 2010 available onstart

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, installation

I have a small application compiled with Visual C++ 2010 x86. You know when you try to start this app on system which doesn't have VC2010 it will crash with msvcp100.dll error. Question is how to detect VC2010 or install it without using another app or installer with lower VC? Maybe i could use some tricks in manifest?

Comment: Why not just package the executable with the required dll's?

Comment: It is a chicken-and-egg problem, you need the CRT before you can start to check.  If it is "small" and does not use any DLLs then compile with /MT so the CRT is linked inside the exe file.  If it does use DLLs then you just have to copy two more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Don't.**

You have better options:

1. Install the VS2010 redistributable along with your program
2. Write in the documentation that users must install it themselves
3. Link it statically (`/MT`) so that it does not need to be on the target machine at all

Otherwise let Windows do the job of reporting when the DLL is missing; it seems to be doing so quite well so far!